# How to add a scaled option to arev package?

Tags: fonts, scaling

The `arev` package provides extended version of BitStream Vera Sans fonts but without `scaled` option.

The `bera` package uses `beraserif`, `berasans` and `beramono` with `scaled` option (via `t1fve.fd`, `t1fvm.fd` and `t1fvs.fd`).

How to add a scaled option to `arev` package?

Or how to create a new virtual font (derived from `arev` package) with a scaled option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example implements a package `arevtext2`, which is similar to the existing package `arevtext`, but adds option `scaled`.
Also the font family names are suffixed with `2`: `fav2` instead of `fav` to avoid name clashes with the existing `arev` files.

```
%%% arevtext2.sty %%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}% 
\ProvidesPackage{arevtext2}%
[2015/06/09 v0.1 Arev Sans Text package with options]%

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  prefix=arevtext@, 
}
\DeclareStringOption[1]{scaled}

% Optionally to accept option "scaled" only as local package option
% and to ignore it as global option.
% \DeclareLocalOptions{scaled}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Package "arevtext" loads package "textcomp", but
% real support for TS1 encoding is not present (missing ".TFM" files)
\RequirePackage{textcomp} % takes text symbols such as \S, \P, \textdagger
                          % from the text font

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fav2}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav2}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm2}

\endinput
```

Then, as example, `t1fav2.fd` is implemented, `fvm2.fd` is left as exercise for the reader.

```
%%% fvm2.fd %%%
\ProvidesFile{t1fav.fd}
   [2015/06/09 Font definitions for T1/fav.]

\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname arevtext@scaled\endcsname\relax
  \let\arevtext@@scaled\@empty
\else
  \edef\arevtext@@scaled{s*[\arevtext@scaled]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{fav2}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{m}{n}{
   <-> \arevtext@@scaled favr8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{m}{it}{
   <-> \arevtext@@scaled favri8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{b}{n}{
   <-> \arevtext@@scaled favb8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{b}{it}{
   <-> \arevtext@@scaled favbi8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * fav/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * fav/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * fav/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * fav/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fav2}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * fav/b/sl}{}

\endinput
```

Test file:

```
%%% test.tex %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled=1.5]{arevtext2}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Hello World! (scaled)\\
{\fontfamily{fav}\selectfont Hello World! (unscaled)}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Much more work is needed for `arevmath`, but this is certainly a good starting point.

Comment: @egreg Is it really much more work? And if I try to do it, how to test it?

Comment: Thanks for this starting point... The easiest solution for me would perhaps ask the author of `arev` package to provide a `scaled` option (for text **and** math)

Comment: @PaulGaborit You have to modify `ot1zavm.fd`, `omlzavm.fd`, `omszavm.fd`, and create a new font family for the large symbols font that presently uses `omsmdbch.fd` at a fixed scaling, so this symbol font should be the same as the present one but scaled 4% less than what you specify in the package option.