# LuaLaTeX | Beamer | fontspec | Define a Sans Serif Math Font

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex, fontspec, sans-serif

> Community, this question does not hold up to my standard research
>   quality. Please excuse if there is an obvious answer. It's a bit of a
>   deadline situation with a late change in requirements.

I have a `beamer` document that is compiled with `LuaTeX`. I have to use a system font (ttf). In the MWE below I use `Consolas` font as a replacement for my actual font (it is commercial).

I want to use a "normal" sans serif math font (via `\usepackage{}`) together with the ttf font. I use `\usepackage{isomath}` in my MWE.

The document compiles but the math is not all sans serif (numbers, sin, alpha, \infty are serif). **I want everything to be sans serif.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\setsansfont{PorscheNextTT}
\setsansfont{Consolas} % Should be available on a Windows system
\usepackage{isomath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}

\begin{align}
1 + 2 &= x\\
y(t) &= \int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha) d\text{t}
\end{align}

Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### MWE with #Consolas# font

[image]

### MWE with my #actual# font

[image]

---

---

> ### Final Solution After Reading the Answers
>
> ```
> \documentclass{beamer}
> \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
>
> % Nice sans serif font
> % Loads arevtext and arevmath which is not necessary in this case (arevmath would be enough)
> \usepackage{arev}
>
> % Here the magic happens
> \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
>
> % Never without...
> \usepackage{mathtools}
>
> % My system font for the main text
> %\setsansfont{PorscheNextTT}
> \setsansfont{Consolas}
>
> % Should be the Last Font package
> % Uses letters and numbers from the main font for math --> very useful
> \usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{frame}
> Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
>
> \begin{align}
> 1 + 2 &= x\\
> y(t) &= \int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha) \mathrm{d}t
> \end{align}
>
> Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
> \end{frame}
>
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> With my Actual Font
>   [image]

Comment: Have you already tried `unicode-math`  and its `\setmathfont`? It has options to appear ISO-like.

Comment: I don't think there exists a sans serif math font in OpenType format.  The closest you can probably get is TeX Gyre DejaVu Math ([showcase](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre-dejavu-math/dejavu-otf-math-2015-poster)) which is slab serif.  Otherwise I know there exists `cmbright` which is a Type1 sans serif math font.  Alternatively you could use `mathastext` to use letters and numerals of the text font in math.

Comment: If your actual text font and the math font look similar enough, maybe `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` could be used?

Comment: @TeXnician No, I did not try that. I do not have much experience with that kind of problem at all (as you can tell :).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for commenting. I do not need/want to use an OpenType font. Maybe I was not clear enough.

Comment: @samcarter The font I load has no math. I "just" want to add a font for the math stuff such as greek letters and function names, In addition, the numbers should appear sans serif.

Comment: The symbols from `arev` look nice, however a little bit too big in comparison to the surrounding font.  If this is still true for your real font https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249379/36296 could be helpful.

Comment: @samcarter Good hint. The `scaled` option (following your link) surely is useful.

Comment: @samcarter I added a screenshot with my actual font. No need to reply. I simply forgot to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your best bet is `mathastext`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9]{DejaVu Sans Mono} % no MS Windows, sorry
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{isomath}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}

  \begin{align}
    1 + 2 &= x\\
    y(t) &= \int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha) \diff t
  \end{align}

  Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just making (actually burning) dinner. I will look into it later. Thanks so far....1 min later...tried it...looks great!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I really appreciate your effort with `\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` (which I did very wrong in my MWE).

Comment: Just read the documentation of the `mathastext` package. This seems to be a very useful package for the/my future.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, I use `arevmath` for sans-serif math in beamer. Also, parts of the `iwona` fonts are helpful (for sans-serif integrals, for example, though big parentheses look a bit weird in this setup).

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setsansfont{PorscheNextTT}
%\setsansfont{Consolas} % Should be available on a Windows system
\setsansfont{Fira Sans} % I'm not on Windows, so Fira Sans instead

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}

\begin{align}
1 + 2 &= x\\
y(t) &= \int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha) d\text{t}
\end{align}

Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of `arevmath` - I will use this. Very good readability.

Answer (score 3):

As a quick hack, you could use your text font for the "normal" letters in math using the `no-math` option of `fontspec`. For all symbols which are not part of your font, the default sans serif ones of beamer will be used.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\setsansfont{PorscheNextTT}
\setsansfont{Consolas} % Should be available on a Windows system

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}

\begin{align}
1 + 2 &= x\\
y(t) &= \int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha) d\text{t}
\end{align}

Testtext. Testtext. \textbf{Testtext.} Testtext. \textcolor{red}{Testtext.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `no-math` did the trick.